# Ergodicity and the tail sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, independence, ergodic-theory

Why is an i.i.d. sequence of random variables indexed in discrete time, $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$, ergodic?  Here, we define ergodicity as follows:

Let $T$ be the left shift operator. i.e. $T( (..., X_{-1}, X_0, X_1, ...) ) = (..., X_0, X_1, X_2, ...)$.  A set $A$ is called ***invariant*** if and only if $$A = \{ \{X_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{Z}} \in B\} = \{ T^n(\{X_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{Z}}) \in B\} \quad \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$$ for some $B$ =  Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$.  It is easy to show that the set of invariant sets is a sigma algebra, and we denote it by $\mathscr{I}_X$.  A process $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is ***ergodic*** if and only if its invariant sigma algebra is trivial; that is, $P(A) \in \{0,1\} \quad \forall A \in \mathscr{I}_X$

It is clear to me that when $X$ is indexed solely with $\mathbb{N}$ and we define shift operator $$T((x_0, x_1, x_2, ...)) = (x_1, x_2, x_3, ...) $$ then any event $A$ such that $$A = \{(X_0, X_1,...) \in B \} = \{T^n((X_0, X_1, ...)) \in B \} = \{(X_n, X_{n+1}, ...) \in B \} \in \sigma(X_n, X_{n+1}, ...)$$ for each $n$ and is thus in the tail sigma field by definition.  Hence by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law we have $P(A) \in \{0,1\}$ and then the invariant sigma algebra for $X$ is clearly trivial so $X$ is ergodic by definition.  However, for the $\mathbb{Z}$ indexed case, I cannot reconcile it in this way and I'm utterly and completely confused, so any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Your definition of invariant does not make sense.  You start by trying to define a property that can be used to determine if a given set $A$ can be called "invariant," and in the process you redefine the set $A$.  The use of $B$ in your definition is also unclear.  If the above property need only hold for some $B$, why not take $B = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ itself, in which case the property always holds.  It would also help to know what kind of sets you are talking about: Sets of real-valued sequences?  Sets of sequences of random variables?

Comment: @Michael It does make sense…I’m defining invariant sets to be those for which there exist some fixed, non changing B such that invariant set corresponding to B = … the form written there. See here: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tim/entropy_19.pdf for an example of how to define ergodicity in this way for the measure preserving system induced by the stationary process X (by its independence, X is obviously stationary). I figured it would be obvious that I’m talking about real valued X by how I’ve defined B

Comment: In other words, a set is invariant if and only if it is equal to $${ X \in B }$$ for some Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ AND the set ${ X \in B }$ satisfies $$ { X \in B } = { T^n(X) \in B }$$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. You can’t just change $B$ like you say, although taking $B = \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb {Z}}$ trivially provides an example of a set which induces an invariant set.

Comment: Anyways, I think I’ve managed to solve the problem on my own and will eventually post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly right: in the two-sided case, i.e. in the space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ with the shift $T$ (I denoted the shift by $T$ not to confuse with $\sigma$-algebra), the invariant $\sigma$-algebra of $T$ is not included in the two-sided tail $\sigma$-algebra. In particular, one can not deduce the ergodicity of the two-sided shift from the triviality of the two-sided tail $\sigma$-algebra (which is indeed true for shift-invariant product measures).

However, the usual proof of the Kolmogorov 0-1 law in the one-sided case can be adapted to show that the two-sided shift is indeed ergodic. To this end you can argue as follows.

1. Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a shift-invariant product measure on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and let $A\subset S^{\mathbb{Z}}$ be a shift-invariant event.
2. For $\epsilon>0$, approximate $A$ by a cylindrical set $C$, in the sense that $\mathbb{P}\left(A\triangle C\right)<\epsilon$.
3. Pick $n$ so that $C':=T^{n}\left(C\right)$ is independent of $C$, and note that also $\mathbb{P}\left(A\triangle C'\right)<\epsilon$.
4. Show that $\left|\mathbb{P}\left(A\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(A\right)^2\right|<\epsilon$, and deduce the triviality of $A$.